# selenium server, selenium client, on an UBUNTU GUI server

Tags: java, python, selenium, ubuntu, ssh

i have a `VPS` with `ubuntu 14.04 LTS` and with the desktop package installed, that mean I can launch firefox from a `ssh -X` session.
To make tests, I launched from my server the selenium standalone server jar `(selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar)`
After launching it, in another ssh session, i just enter python commands :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
```

And after that, following the instructions from 
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#using-selenium-with-remote-webdriver, I enter :

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(
command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

After 45sec, i have lots of errors in both server window and client window.
Here is the main error :

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
>       Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays

I saw some people with the same problem, but even with the latest java and selenium versions, i still got this issue. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is your firefox version??

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 48.0

Comment: Try then using provided answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying `selenium 3` with latest firefox version. To support latest firefox with `selenium 3`, need to [download latest `geckodriver` executable from this link](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and extract it into you system at any location.

Now to run `selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar` use below command :-

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver = "path/to/downloaded geckodriver"
```

Now you need to set capability with `marionette` property to `true` to support latest firefox with `selenium 3` as below :-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

# Tell the Python bindings to use Marionette.
caps["marionette"] = True

driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = caps)
```

**Note** :- For more [information about `marionette` follow this `Mozilla` official page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver)

Comment: Tried with an older version of selenium (2.53) same issue, going to try yours ;)

Comment: @saperlipopette Ya sure you can use same answer to support latest firefox with geckodriver with selenium 3 as well as selenium 2. Let me know if you have any problem..:)

Comment: Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver

Comment: Is this error occurred when you run `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.0.0-beta3.jar -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver = "path/to/downloaded geckodriver"` at command line??

Comment: Have a look [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36831030/exception-in-thread-main-error-in-eclipse-when-trying-to-run-testng-class) may be it helps