# selenium server and firefox on ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, firefox

I have a server where selenium server standalone (beta3) jar is running. I have a little python script which opens firefox, clicks on buttons..etc and then closes. It was working perfectly since today. I bought a new server also under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop, and when my python script executes, it well opens firefox, but then firefox quits immediatly (no crash pop up).
Here is my python code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

driver = webdriver.Remote(
           command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
           desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX)
```

When i run this, i see in the jar server process the execution of the new session, then firefox opens, and quits (*without pop up*). I have no error in the server process console.
But in my python script process, i have this error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

It died since it closed (alone). Can't figure out why this doesn't work. It was working perfectly on my other server.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Same question You're asking again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39333726/selenium-server-selenium-client-on-an-ubuntu-gui-server

Comment: Nope it's another one. Here i can run selenium server, from a VNC viewer, it's just that firefox quit instantly. In the other post i want to run selenium from an ssh session